# how to read enter input on c

Tags: c

This function will be called by the menu.

```
void exponentiation()
{

  int i, result = 0, first, second;

  printf("\n%s\n%s\n\n%s",
         "1) Exponentiation",
         "------------------",
         "Enter 1st integer: ");
  scanf("%d", &first);

  printf("Enter 2nd integer: ");
  scanf("%d", &second);

  printf("%d raised to %d equals %d\n", first, second, result);
  main();
}
```

From this function I need to read the user input, if the user input is "enter" without any integer, it should be going back to the menu which is calling the main().

I already tried to get the input.
For example:

```
if(first == '\n')

{main();}
```

or

```
if(first == 10) /**which is 10 is ASCII code for enter**/

{main()}
```

Both ways it didn't work at all, any suggestions?

Comment: Which manual did you read prior to asking this question? ... and what makes you think '\n' is *always 10* in C? C doesn't require ASCII...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> both ways it didn't work at all, any suggestion

The function `scanf` returns the number of items it successfully scanned. You should check its return and go back if it doesn't matches your expectations.

---

Also you should know **`%d` ignores whitespace**. So if the user hits return without entering an integer, `scanf` simply skips over it and waits for something else.

If you insist on not ignoring whitespace this way, you should avoid `scanf` and use other input methods such as `fgets`. Get input from the user line by line and use `sscanf`, `strtoul` and `strtok` to make sense of it.